# Replace multiline string by another multiline string in a markdown file on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, find-and-replace, perl

I want to replace a multiline string in a markdown by another one (also multiline). I think perl is the best option.

E.g. i want to replace

```
## Exercise 1 
some text
some more text

## Points
```

by

```
## Exercise 1 
some new text
some more different text

## Points
```

This is what i have:

```
FIND=(##\ Exercise\ 1).*(##\ Points)
REPLACE=`cat schema.md`
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/$FIND/$REPLACE/smg' P.md
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Because you have the `perl` command in single quotes, `bash` isn't going to do variable substitution, so you're telling perl to replace the literal string `$FIND` with the literal string `$REPLACE`. Try double quotes instead, although then you might have problems with metacharacters in the substitution, but at least it will get you a little further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the right kind of quotes. Parentheses have special meaning in many shells, and shell variables won't work inside single quotes. Also, if your replacement contains such as `/` or `$`, the Perl syntax will be wrong and the replacement will fail.

You can use the following script:

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN { undef $/; } s/^## Exercise 1.*^## Points.*?^/`cat schema.md`/sme' P.md
```

Explanations:

- `BEGIN { undef $/; }` makes Perl read the whole file in one go.
- `s/A/B/sme` finds A across multiple lines, handles backreferences in B, evaluates the new B and uses the result as the replacement.
- `^## Exercise 1.*^## Points.*?^` will match a range from a line starting with `## Exercise 1` to a line starting with `## Points` and then until the next line begins.
- `` `cat schema.md` `` means that when a match is found, Perl will execute `cat schema.md` as a shell command. Thus, the new text will be the contents of schema.md.